# Search Button VBA : Find values in Excel cell and populate fields based upon finding results

Tags: excel, vba, forms, loops, button

I am working on an Excel form which has a text box **txtSearch** where user inputs some value. On pressing
search button **btn_search2** if value is found on **Sheet1** some fields should be populated by row where the value is found. Else system should return a message : Data not found.

My code works correctly if I enter values from column *A* but doesnt search other columns.

Any thoughts about this?

My code as below:

```
    Dim iSearch As Long, i As Long
    
    iSearch = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    
    For i = 1 To iSearch
    
        If Trim(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)) <> Trim(txtSearch.Text) And i = iSearch Then
        
            MsgBox ("Invalid data")
            txtSearch.Text = ""
            txtSearch.SetFocus
            
        End If
    
        If Trim(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)) = Trim(txtSearch.Text) Then
        
            txtRef.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
            txtFirstname.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
            txtSurname.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3)
            txtAddress.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4)
    
            txtPostCode.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5)
            txtTelephone.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6)
            txtDateReg.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 7)
            txtProve.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 8)
            txtMemberType.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 9)
            txtMemberFees.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 10)
            
            Exit For
            
        End If
        
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to search all rows and columns in the current data region for the value txtSearch but your code is only searching all rows in column A. Is that correct?

If so, this is happening because your code block that checks the values in each row against txtSearch is only checking cell (i,1) in each row. In cell indexing, the first value (i in your case) is the row number and the second (1 in your case) is the column number. Since the value of i is changing, you're checking multiple rows. Since the value of the second index (1) is not changing, you are only checking column 1 ("A").

To check all columns, you would need an inner for-loop to iterate through all columns in each row. So you need another variable to check the total number of columns and another loop to traverse them all, like so:

```
Dim iSearch As Long, i As Long
Dim jSearch As Long, j As Long
    
    iSearch = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    jSearch = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
    
    For i = 1 To iSearch
        
        For j = 1 to jSearch

            If Trim(Sheet1.Cells(i, j)) <> Trim(txtSearch.Text) And i = iSearch And j = jSearch Then
        
                MsgBox ("Invalid data")
                txtSearch.Text = ""
                txtSearch.SetFocus
            
            End If
    
        If Trim(Sheet1.Cells(i, j)) = Trim(txtSearch.Text) Then
        
            txtRef.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
            txtFirstname.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
            txtSurname.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3)
            txtAddress.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4)
    
            txtPostCode.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5)
            txtTelephone.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6)
            txtDateReg.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 7)
            txtProve.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 8)
            txtMemberType.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 9)
            txtMemberFees.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 10)
            
            Exit For
            
        End If
    Next j
        
    Next i
```

You can also clean up your code a bit by adding a With block and by only checking "Trim(...)<>Trim(...)" if you're at the last row and column, since in all other cases you'd want to keep searching anyways:

```
Dim iSearch As Long, i As Long
Dim jSearch As Long, j As Long
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        iSearch = .Rows.Count
        jSearch = .Columns.Count
    End With
    
    For i = 1 To iSearch
        
        For j = 1 to jSearch
        If Trim(Sheet1.Cells(i, j)) = Trim(txtSearch.Text) Then
        
            txtRef.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
            txtFirstname.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
            txtSurname.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3)
            txtAddress.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4)
    
            txtPostCode.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5)
            txtTelephone.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6)
            txtDateReg.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 7)
            txtProve.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 8)
            txtMemberType.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 9)
            txtMemberFees.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 10)
            
            Exit For
            
        End If
    Next j
        
    Next i
  
    MsgBox ("Invalid data")
    txtSearch.Text = ""
    txtSearch.SetFocus
```

Comment: Thx Allison everything works fine. I had to remove MsgBox ("Invalid data") because it prints the results of search and shows this message box also. Is there any workaround if there is more than one search result? Maybe to print them in a list?

Comment: Sure, you could print them in a list. You could save the positions of all the rows with search results (e.g. have an array SearchResults and save the row number i for each matching result, then have a loop at the end to go through all values at the rows indicated in SearchResults and print each one) or just print as you go. The MsgBox is my error, I thought it said `Exit Sub` not `Exit For`--if it said ExitSub the MsgBox would only appear if no result was found, otherwise the subroutine would end once a result was found.